# Is this possible - change text value displayed in a div after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a strange idea, hopefully it's possible. I have a script that dynamically loads a div with different text values (this is a given variable, can't change anything here). Is it possible to change these values after the page has loaded? This is my idea:

1. The page is loaded
2. The script loads the div with text (e. g. one phrase is "Welcome here"
3. New script changes some of the values displayed (e. g. the previous one becomes "How are you? Welcome!"

Any ideas?

EDIT

Here is the example of the code:

```
<div id="one" class="one">First text
<div class="two">Second text
<label class="three">Third text</label>
<option value="1">ValueOne</option>
<a>Link text</a>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are different types of selectors involved, while some of the phrases don't have any selectors (this is just a part of the code). After the page loading finishes, this shoud look like this:

```
<div id="one" class="one">FirstTextChanged
<div class="two">SecondTextChanged
<label class="three">ThirdTextChanged</label>
<option value="1">ValueOneChanged</option>
<a>LinkTextChanged</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would be what Javascript and Jquery do! Modify data dynamically.

Comment: a JsFiddle would be useful here!

Comment: need to see some existing  code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UPhUb/1/

waits 5 seconds after page loads, then changes the text. Simple.

```
changeText = function(text, newText){
    var currentText = $('#welcome').html();  

    $('#welcome').html(currentText.replace(text,newText));
};

window.setTimeout(function(){changeText('Welcome.', 'How are you?')}, 5000);
```

Updated per your comment: now when you call `changeText` you pass two arguments, the text you want swapped out and the new text you want in. Without seeing your code, this is as close as I think I can get.

Comment: That's it, but the problem is that I don't have a selector for every phrase. Is it possible to type the exact phrases that I want to change in the function?

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you! Some problems left - 1. If you have the same css class in HTML code, it will change that too. E. g. from <div class="WelcomeClass>Welcome</div> to <div class="How are You?Class>How are You?</div> 2. If one value shows up multiple times, only the first instance will be affected 3. If a text is between option tags (<option value="STH"></option>), how to change that?

Comment: The third one is solved, I found "closer" selector and that works.

Comment: Everything resolved: 1. Try to find closer selector too. 2. Add another function (instead of "changeText = function(text, newText)" use e. g. "changeText2 = function(text, newText)" and change the second appearance of "changeText" to "changeText2". Thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is:

In javascript

```
 document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "New html";
```

In jQuery

```
$("#div1").html("New html");
```

Comment: The same thing as with the first answer - I know the exact phrases that will show up, so it would be easier just to use one id div selector (e. g. #changer) and choose which value to change with which phrase (e. g. --#changer "originaltext"-- to --"changedtext"--

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with jQuery.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/r5uaV/1/

Now if there is a specific thing you're wanting to do, post up some HTML, as well as what you want to do, and we can help more.  I just posted a general example of how it can be done with jQuery.

Comment: That's the behavior I need, but it's slightly more complicated. 1. It should happen without clicking, actually the user should see only the 2nd version of the text. 2. I know the exact phrases that will show up, so it would be easier just to use one id div selector (e. g. #changer) and choose which value to change with which phrase (e. g. --#changer "originaltext"-- to --"changedtext"--

Comment: You need even less code to do that!  Here is an edited Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/r5uaV/2/

Comment: I have updated my question with the sample of the code. This example would be perfect if it would target exactly "Original Text" phrase instead of its selector.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/r5uaV/12/ If I am not wrong is this what you are trying ??